# How to hide and show depending on div height

Tags: jquery

I have a `<div>` with **id** `#emailBody`

```
#emailBody {
    width:100%;
    min-width:500px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    max-height:90px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Now inside this is from emails received, so some emails will fit inside the `90px height`, however when I have long emails they do not.

So I put `overflow:hidden` to hide the excess email and only show `90px` worth of it.

What I want to do now is if the email is longer than the `90px height`, to show a button that can extend the height to show the full email, maybe get rid of the `max-height` and replace with `height:inherit`.

How do I achieve this? Because with the `overflow:hidden` on I cannot use the `max-height`.

Please help

Comment: Probably going to be limited as you want to do this in an email. From my knowledge I think it would be impossible to create a fully cross-email client solution. But there may be some people who know better than me.

Comment: I don't know if it can tell you it's height, but why not put the button there anyway?

Comment: no I don't want to do this in an email, emails are injected using .net into this div

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I've improved the CSS to make it slightly more reliable.

Without JS, I don't believe that there is a perfect way to do this. Here is probably the best approach to try:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="email-content">Email Content</div>
  <div class="show-more"><a href="#">Show More</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  max-height: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  // other styling
}

.show-more {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.show-more a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You'll need to tweak the `max-height` value to make everything line up as expected. You might actually want to use `em` values, along with specifying `line-height`.

Using this markup, the `show-more` link won't appear until the height of the wrapper extends down far enough. If you copy and paste the code as is into an HTML document, you won't see the link. If you replace `Email Content` with several copies of `Email Content<br>`, it will appear at the bottom of the box.

This guarantees that the link shows up at the bottom of the box when `max-height` is reached. The only problem is that the height of `wrapper` may not increase in distinct chunks, so the `show-more` link might be partially cut off.